Polkadot.js does not accept Polkadot private key exported from JAXX wallet, what can I do?
I have a Polkadot private key exported from a JAXX wallet that stopped working. The key is 16-bit (128 bytes long) but Polkadot.js doesn't accept it, what can I do?
